# Extract all objects that are part of a hash map List with Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a HashMap that consists of a list of objects:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> map;
```

I would like to extract all the employee objects from each list into a new list.

I tried to do the following but either does not give me what I want or is an error.

```
List<Asset> as = selectedAssetsMap.values().stream().findAny().get().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Asset> s = selectedAssetsMap.values().stream().forEach(l -> 1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
List<Asset> a1 = selectedAssetsMap.values().stream().map(l -> l.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The first version gives me only the first set of Employee objects. The second one are wrong... Any help/direction will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `flatMap` operator like this.

```
List<Employee> allEmps = map.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```